# A bounded PDE implies identically $0$ solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, contest-math

The problem statement: Suppose that the function $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has continuous partial derivatives and satisfies the equation

$$ h(x, y) = a\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x, y) + b\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x, y)$$

for some constants $a,b$. Prove that if there is a constant $M$ such that $|h(x, y)|\leq M$ for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $h$ is identically zero.

I wanted to see if the below solution was complete. Any feedback on rigor is greatly appreciated:

Solution:
Suppose there was a $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $h(x_0, y_0) \neq 0$. Then WLOG, we can suppose that $h(x_0, y_0) > 0$ since $h(x,y)$ is a solution implies $-h(x,y)$ is also a solution. Therefore:
\begin{equation} \label{a36e1}
    a\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) + b\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)>0
\end{equation}

This can be interpreted as the dot product between the vectors $\langle a, b \rangle$ and $\nabla h(x, y)$. We know that the directional derivative of $\nabla_{\langle a, b \rangle}h(x, y) = \frac{\langle a, b \rangle\cdot \nabla f}{|\langle a, b \rangle|} = \frac{h(x, y)}{|\langle a, b \rangle|}$. We can thus conclude that in the direction of $\langle a, b \rangle$, $h(x, y)>h(x_0, y_0)$. We have:
\begin{align}
    f(x_0 + ka, y_0 + kb) &= \int_0^k \nabla_{\langle a, b \rangle}h(x_0+ta, y_0+tb)|\langle a, b \rangle| dk + h(x_0, y_0)\\
    &=  \int_0^k \frac{h(x, y)}{|\langle a, b \rangle|}|\langle a, b \rangle| dk + h(x_0, y_0)\\
    &> \int_0^k h(x_0, y_0) dk + h(x_0, y_0) \label{a36e2}
\end{align}
The RHS clearly goes to infinity as $k \rightarrow \infty$. This contradicts the boundedness of $h$ and thus we conclude $h$ is identically zero.

Comment: Looks very good and well written.

Comment: It might be easier to do it like this. Define $f(t)=h(ta+x_0, tb+y_0)$. Then we get $f'(t)=f(t)$ and $f(0)=h(x_0,y_0)$. Thus $$h(ta+x_0,tb+y_0)=f(t)=e^t h(x_0,y_0)$$ which is only bounded if $h(x_0, y_0)=0$. Thus, $h=0$.

Comment: Oh you transformed a PDE into an ODE? That is very clever!